# How to change days format to total second in pandas data frame?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

[[image: 1]

This day format 17 days 00:00:00
To Format in seconds : 1641600.0
please tell the syntax for this pandas dataframe

Comment: 17 days in the format of seconds are 1468800, not 1641600.

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag. (Even if it *were* related to machine learning, your question isn't.)

Comment: `df['avg_delay'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['avg_delay']).dt.total_seconds()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pd.Timedelta` and `.view` methods:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create a sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([{'delta_days':'17 days 00:00:00'}, {'delta_days':'19 days 00:00:00'}])

# Convert to the format of seconds
df['converted_delta_days'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['delta_days']).view(np.int64) / 1e9
```

|  | delta_days | converted_delta_days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 17 days 00:00:00 | 1468800.0 |
| 1 | 19 days 00:00:00 | 1641600.0 |

Comment: After reading tdy's comment to the OP's question, I found that I unnecessarily used the `.apply` method in my answer. So I modified that part. Plus, `.total_seconds` method looks superior, so you don't have a reason to use the `.view` method to get the seconds format any more.

Answer (score 0):

i think u didnot use map function properly in average delay

map_cust_num=maindata.groupby("name_customer")['Delay'].mean(numeric_only=False)
maindata['avg_delay']=maindata['name_customer'].map(map_cust_num)

use this in pervious line of code.

highradius which house?